# /dev/mem file descriptor returning 0

Tags: c, linux, memory, file-descriptor

I am trying to access /dev/mem by mmap. I have disabled CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM  in kernel config. when I am trying to get the file descriptor fd, it always returns 0 which is the file descriptor for Standard input. What is going wrong here?

```
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
int main ()
{
        int fd =  -1;
        if(fd = open("/dev/mem",O_SYNC) < 0){
                printf("Error opening file \n");
                close(fd);
                return (-1);
        }
        else printf("/dev/mem fd: %d \n", fd);


        return 0;
}
```

output: /dev/mem fd: 0

Comment: Use more than one line and you won't have this problem:  `int fd = open("/dev/mem",O_RDONLY|O_SYNC); if ( fd < 0 ) ...`.  Stuffing the assignment into the `if` condition is a **BAD IDEA** because it leads to bugs just like this.

Comment: COmpile code with all warnings enabled and the compiler will catch this. Use -Wall

Answer (score 4):

```
if(fd = open("/dev/mem",O_SYNC) < 0){
```

You've messed up the operator precedence. That's parsed as

```
fd = (open("/dev/mem",O_SYNC) < 0)
```

not as

```
(fd = open("/dev/mem",O_SYNC)) < 0
```

as you apparently expect. Always compile with `-Wall` and don't ignore the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs

> Upon successful completion, the function shall open the file and
>   return a non-negative integer representing the lowest numbered unused
>   file descriptor. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned and errno set to
>   indicate the error. No files shall be created or modified if the
>   function returns -1.

So `0` means there was no error.